# How to export table/data from AWS RDS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, bcp

In AWS RDS SQL Server, for import/export we can use these functions

```
rds_upload_to_s3 
exec msdb.dbo.rds_upload_to_s3 
        @rds_file_path='D:\S3\seed_data\data.csv',
        @s3_arn_of_file='arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/new_data.csv',
        @overwrite_file=1;

rds_download_from_s3
exec msdb.dbo.rds_download_from_s3
        @s3_arn_of_file='arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/bulk_data.csv',
        @rds_file_path='D:\S3\seed_data\data.csv',
        @overwrite_file=1;
```

however, it does not mention how to bcp out tables or select query data to D drive or S3 bucket.

If we use Import/Export Wizard, it does not recognize the destination S3 bucket or the D:\S3 location.

What are the other options we have. There are some app jobs which need bcp in/out from SQL Server.

Thanks

Comment: hi @Kris. Did find any options to export data from RDS SQL Server to S3?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Integrating an Amazon RDS for SQL Server DB instance with Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/User.SQLServer.Options.S3-integration.html)

Maybe you have to activate S3_INTEGRATION in IAM for the RDS